# 'Method API not supported on this platform' after Trigger.io update

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, trigger.io, arm64

After Triggerio.io update to v2.2.2 and update of all modules to 'arm64 support' I can't run my app on iphone 5s/6/6+ simulator. None of native modules are working. Each call returns: 'Method API not supported on this platform'.

All other devices are working fine. Any ideas how to fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing a rebuild of your app:

- Add the "parameters" module to your app.
- Give it a new key/value pair e.g. "bumpme": "1"
- Clean out your app's cache directories:

  rm -rf .template development
- Force a remote rebuild of your app:

  forge build ios -f

Comment: Thanks! It works now :] The only question, why did I need to add "parameters" module? Does this force rebuild?

Comment: Trigger.io caches your last build and uses a hash of the config.json file to invalidate the cache. Making a change to a key in the parameters module is thus an easy and reliable way to force a full rebuild :)